# My B-1 visa was rejected five months ago, will this impact a new B-2 application?

Tags: visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I applied for a B-1 visa to attend some business meetings in USA with the company I provide consultancy to and it was rejected under [INA 214 (b)](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/denials.html) five months ago. The refusal reason is (quoted from the linked governmental website):

> #### What does a visa denial under INA section 214(b) mean?
>
> This law applies only to nonimmigrant visa categories. If you are refused a visa under section 214(b), it means that you:
>
> - Did not sufficiently demonstrate to the consular officer that you qualify for the nonimmigrant visa category you applied for; and/or
> - Did not overcome the presumption of immigrant intent, required by law, by sufficiently demonstrating that you have strong ties to your home country that will compel you to leave the United States at the end of your temporary stay. (H-1B and L visa applicants, along with their spouse and any minor children, are excluded from this requirement.)

I'm planning on going there for a holiday this time, so thinking of re-applying for a B-2.

Will my previous rejected attempt have any effect this time?

Comment: What was the refusal reason?

Comment: @JoErNanO He gave the refusal reason, but perhaps not enough detail about it. It won't help to reapply unless circumstances have changed and you are now able to demonstrate strong ties to your country.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I understand the reason is 214(b) however not everyone on the website is familiar with INA paragraphs, or knows them by heart. IMHO rendering the reason explicit improves the quality of the question and it's answerability (see my edit).

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's also possible that circumstances haven't changed, but a subsequent application might do a better job of demonstrating the circumstances.  Sometimes people omit evidence under the mistaken impression that it is not important.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you've had a previous refusal will not count against you as such.  ie, there's no different process for someone that has had a previous refusal for the reason you have.

However, the consulate staff that are processing your new application WILL have access to the details of your previous application, along with the notes that the previous staff recorded as to why they refused your application.  The person processing your new application will take these notes into account when deciding whether to approve your new visa.

If you are aware of a reason why you suspect that your visa was previously rejected then I would suggest taking specific evidence with you to help counter such issues.  For 214(b) that could include things like bank statements, housing details, detailed itinerary for your time in the US, return travel information, etc